# States diagonal in the tensor product of Bell states.

Tags: research-level, specific-reference, quantum-information, bells-inequality

Bell-diagonal states are 2-qubit states that are diagonal in the [Bell basis](http://www.quantiki.org/wiki/Bell_basis). Since those states lie in $\mathbb{C}^{2} \otimes \mathbb{C}^{2}$, the [Peres-Horodecki criterion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peres%E2%80%93Horodecki_criterion)  is a sufficient condition to show separability and it's also pretty easy to check: $\rho = \sum_{i \in [0,3]}\lambda_i|\psi_{i}\rangle\langle\psi_{i}|  $ is PPT (or separable) if and only if $Tr(\rho) \geq 2\lambda_i \geq 0$ for every $i$.
(Here {$|\psi_{i}\rangle$} are the Bell states)

In my research I am dealing with a generalization of those states. In particular, my question is about states in $\mathbb{C}^{2^d} \otimes \mathbb{C}^{2^d}$ that are diagonal in the basis given by the $d$-fold tensor product of Bell states.

For example, for $d=2$, the states I am considering are diagonal in the basis:
$$
|\psi_{0}\rangle\otimes|\psi_{0}\rangle,|\psi_{0}\rangle\otimes|\psi_{1}\rangle, \ldots,|\psi_{3}\rangle\otimes|\psi_{3}\rangle.
$$

I am wondering the following:

> are there some nice criteria already known to check when these states are PPT
>   or separable?

Notice that those states are in general different from the states diagonal in what is called the generalized Bell basis in literature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try Theorem 12 in (the arXiv version) of http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0411098. What I call "lattice states" there should exactly be the class of states you are interested in.